# Limit x-axis to current week

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, week-number

I try to limit the x-axis of a plot with several figures to the current week. So if we are now in week 45 all weeks from 1 till 45 should be displayed, but not from 46 onwards. I cannot get any `xlim` command to work e.g. `xlim(1,45)` returns Error:

> Discrete value supplied to continuous scale.

Perhaps this has to do with the fact that the variable week is a factor, but this is necessary for correct plotting (no decimals). Any solutions?

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(object = sample(c("A","B","C","D"),100,replace = TRUE),
                  week = sample(c(1:52),100,replace = TRUE),
                  year = sample(c(2016,2017,2018),100,replace = TRUE),
                  count = sample(c(0:10),100,replace = TRUE))

ggplot(dat, aes(factor(week), count )) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity" , aes(fill = factor(year)), position = position_dodge2(width = 0.9, preserve = "single")) + 
  facet_wrap(~ object, ncol = 2, scales = "free_y") +
  labs(x = "Week", y = "Count") +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Year")
```

[image: output for the above data]

Comment: I don't understand your argument weeks as factors are necessary for correct plotting. I get 152 weeks with factors, but the correct number of weeks without factors. IMO you simply could do `ggplot(dat[dat$week < 45, ], aes(week, count)) + ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can restrict in data itself.

Try with the below code :

```
data<-dat%>% filter(week < format(Sys.Date(),"%V")) ## filtering based on current week

Plotting :

ggplot(data, aes(factor(week), count )) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity" , aes(fill = factor(year)), position = position_dodge2(width = 0.9, preserve = "single")) + 
  facet_wrap(~ object, ncol = 2, scales = "free_y") +
  labs(x = "Week", y = "Count") +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Year") +theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0.4))
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

Why not add a `filter` before the plot call for `week`:

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(object = sample(c("A","B","C","D"),100,replace = TRUE),
                  week = sample(c(1:52),100,replace = TRUE),
                  year = sample(c(2016,2017,2018),100,replace = TRUE),
                  count = sample(c(0:10),100,replace = TRUE))

dat %>% 
  filter(week <= 45) %>% # add filter before plot
  ggplot(aes(factor(week), count )) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity" , aes(fill = factor(year)), position = position_dodge2(width = 0.9, preserve = "single")) + 
  facet_wrap(~ object, ncol = 2, scales = "free_y") +
  labs(x = "Week", y = "Count") +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Year")
```

[image]